# A program that prints the following code

Tags: java

I've been trying to print a pattern in which there is a right triangle and its mirror image and I am unable to figure out the mirror image part.

Pattern:

```
A       A
AB     BA
ABC   CBA
ABCD DCBA
ABCDEDCBA
```

Pattern I've been able to print:

```
A         A 
AB       AB
ABC     ABC
ABCD   ABCD
ABCDE ABCDE
```

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int i,j,k,l;
    System.out.print("Enter the numbers of rows you want to print: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int ch = 65,ch1 = 65;
        for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
            ch++;
        }
        for (k=n;k>=i+1;k--)
        {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }

        for (l=1;l<=i;l++)
        {
            System.out.print((char)ch1);
            ch1++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to your code:

- `i,j,k,l;` What is this? Did you forget the type, i.e. `int i,j,k,l;`? If so, remove the line, and declare the variables where they are used, e.g. `for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)`.
  You can then also reuse the variable names.
- <del>If you want `ch` to be a `char`, why not make it a `char`? You should also use `'A'` to initialize it, not `65`.</del>
- <del>Why do you need two `ch` variables? Just use one.</del>
- Last two points are moot, since you should just calculate the value directly, e.g. `(char)('A' + j)`.
- Now that you've done that, the last loop should count backwards, to get letters in reverse order. ***(mirror image part)***
- Since you want middle letter (`E` in your example) to only print once, that means you need *odd* number of spaces when not printing `E` and no spaces when printing the *single* `E`. Easiest way to do that, is for last line to be handled separately.
- No need to add empty string when printing newline, i.e. `println("")` → `println()`.
- Don't put `;` after your method, i.e. `};` → `}`.

This is the result:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("Enter the numbers of rows you want to print: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    // Print lines 1 to n-1
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { // count up (i = 1 .. n-1)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { // count up (j = 0 .. i-1)
            System.out.print((char)('A' + j));
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < 2 * (n - i); j++) { // odd number of spaces
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) { // count down (j = i-1 .. 0)
            System.out.print((char)('A' + j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // Now print last line
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // count up (j = 0 .. n-1)
        System.out.print((char)('A' + j));
    }
    for (int j = n - 2; j >= 0; j--) { // count down (j = n-2 .. 0)
        System.out.print((char)('A' + j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i,j,k,l;
    System.out.print("Enter the numbers of rows you want to print: \n");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int ch = 65,ch1 = 65;
        for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
            ch++;
        }

        for (k=2*(n+1-i)-3;k>0;k--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (l=1;l<=i;l++)
        {
            System.out.print((char)(ch1-l+i));
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Doesn't give the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, you should take advantage of a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as not only does it allow you to [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(char)) characters, but it also allows you to [`reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) the string, which is perfect for your mirroring scenario. Leaving the spaces as the only problem to handle, which [`Arrays.fill()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(char[],%20char)) may be able to help with

In your code you've provided the value of 'A' (65) here: `int ch = 65,ch1 = 65;`
to use when printing. However `for` loops also work with `char`, meaning you can integrate this logic into the structure

E.g. if the loop initialization was `'A'` this would be the same as starting at `'A'`. The increment would then update this to `'B'`, `'C'` etc as it loops assuming you were using `++`. There are tutorials available to better explain this

By using variable names that convey what you are trying to do, it makes it easier to condense / optimise your code as you're writing it. Hopefully the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) at the end of this answer can highlight the benefits of this, such as this line: `int numberOfSpacesNeeded = numberOfRows - rowIndex;`

---

SSCCE:

```
public class MirrorPrinting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the numbers of rows you want to print: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfRows = scan.nextInt();

        StringBuilder currentRow = new StringBuilder();
        for(int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= numberOfRows; rowIndex++){
            for(char currentCharacter = 'A'; currentCharacter < rowIndex + 'A'; currentCharacter++){
                currentRow.append(currentCharacter);
            }

            int numberOfSpacesNeeded = numberOfRows - rowIndex;
            char[] spaces = new char[numberOfSpacesNeeded];
            Arrays.fill(spaces, ' ');

            System.out.println(currentRow.toString() + new String(spaces) + currentRow.reverse().toString());

            //Reset StringBuilder
            currentRow = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe you could append my code as I am a novice to JAVA Programming and don't know the library and methods so clearly.

Comment: I was hoping that introducing something new could help you in future, which is why I included some links in my answer to where more information was available. I'm happy to answer any questions you have on what I posted